# I don't know how to rewrite program to use objects instead of integer values, having few issues

Tags: java, object

I was given a program which uses integer input to calculate Priority Queue.

How to rewrite code to represent object instead of integers?

The issue with my revision is that my modification fail to run and say

Comment: What would be the meaning for objects different than integers ? What would be the comparison ? Would it be based on Comparable ?

Comment: @dystroy, I know as much as you do :) I'm just scratching my head on this :D

Comment: I assume there is a reason you can't use the built in `PriorityQueue` and can read its code to see how it works ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your objects aren't strings but integers (long). So don't try to parse them.

You could change

```
  if( Long.parseLong((String) item) > Long.parseLong((String) queArray[j]) )
```

to

```
  if ((Long) item) > (Long) queArray[j]) )
```

You could also change

```
public void insert(Object item)
```

to

```
public void insert(Long item)
```

in order to avoid the cast.

But that wouldn't work for other types of objects than Long so isn't probably useful to you.

If you want to be able to compare any kind of object, you can provide a [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) :

You would define `PriorityQ` as `PriorityQ<T>` (using generics), add a `setComparator(Comparator comparator)` method, and define your insert method like this :

```
 public void insert(T item)
 ...

 if ((comparator.compare(item, queArray[j])>0) {
```

This means changing also the queArray array to a `T[]` type.

Comment: Yes, the problem is that I must change this program to use any object, meaning it must use generics.

Comment: You can't change the program to use any object because internally you use a comparison.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you call the `insert(Object item)` function with an Integer type value.

Then you try to cast it to String this way: `(String) item`.

This won't work. Use `item.toString()` to **convert** something to String.

And while you're at it, you should read this: [Java type casting](http://www.javabeginner.com/learn-java/java-object-typecasting)